# Python Reg Expression - how can I print out the search results with re.search?

Tags: python, regex, search

I believe the re.search produces TRUE / FALSE results only, but is there a way to gather the results (besides using findall)?  I am under the impression that in a line of text, once the re.search finds a match, it goes no further because it is now TRUE.  Maybe this is the improper use of re.search because it should be just to find True and False and shouldn't be used to gather.
I did some research and found the .group() command, although I am not sure how it works.

```
import re
str =" french-fries and french-toast"
is_it_there = re.search(r'french-\S+', str)
if is_it_there:
   print(is_it_there.group())
else:
   print("did not find")
```

Should I just use re.findall for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), it returns an iterator of match objects, which appears to be what you're looking for:

```
for match in re.finditer('french-\S+', 'french-fries and french-toast'):
     print(match.group())

french-fries
french-toast
```

Comment: @netrate If you're asking whether it looks for all matches, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

With **re.findall**

```
import re
match = re.findall('french-\S+', 'french-fries and french-toast')
if match:
    for m in match:
        print m
```